# Прервать выполнение метода

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод `_updater.Update()`; В нем запускается отдельный поток, который занимается проверкой наличия обновлений. Я хочу прекратить его выполнение нажатием на кнопку

```
private void breakBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // что тут должно быть?
}
```

То есть мне надо прервать работу отдельного потока. Подскажите как можно это сделать?

Comment: добавьте метод `_updater.Update`. В общем случае - никак

Comment: К сожалению Вы не поняли..  private void breakBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _updater.Update();
        }      если я сделаю так то я вызову метод, а мне надо прекратить его выполнение

Comment: Это вы не поняли :-) я имел ввиду: добавьте код этой функции в пост, а так же добавьте что такое `_updater`

Comment: в  _updater.Update() запускается Thread / Task?

Comment: Или я не понял) Код очень большой. В классе содержатся методы, проверки на наличие обновлений, само обновление, докачка файла. А вызываю я его так - _updater.Update(); В этом методе есть пул потоков  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(unused =>

Comment: _добавьте код этой функции в пост,_, хотя бы - добавьте определение этой функции, в противном случае ответ: никак

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @МаксФадеев _"есть пул потоков ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem"_ --  такое извне - никак.

Answer (score 5):

В Thread или Task передается CancellationToken и проверяется его свойство IsCancellationRequested. Если равно true, то надо завершить работу.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

partial class MainWindow : Window {
    CancellationTokenSource cts;
    Model m;
    public MainWindow() {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.DataContext = m = new Model();
        m.Update(cts.Token);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}


class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public void Update(CancellationToken ct) {
        var c = SynchronizationContext.Current; // запомнить текущий поток
        Task.Run(() => {
            // работаем пока не будет вызван cts.Cancel() 
            while (ct.IsCancellationRequested == false) {  
                c.Post(o => {  // передать данные в основной поток
                    this.State = o.ToString();
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("State"));
                }
                , DateTime.Now.Ticks);
                Task.Delay(500).Wait();
            }
        }, ct);
    }
    public string State { get; private set; }
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="300" Height="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding State}" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click" Content="Cancel" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: CancellationToken решает поставленный автором вопрос, но по моему таки ему не поможет в его конкретном случае. Ковыряться с чужим кодом, разбираясь в логике, лень, так что надеюсь на то, что автор сам разберется, как должна вести себя программа при попытке прекращения обновления. Или тут даже не прекращение нужно, а пауза.

Answer (score 3):

Не зная кода метода тяжело предложить вариант, но в общем случае заведите переменную (bool), которую будут видеть оба метода (выполняющий работу и прерывания). При запуске выполняющего метода присвойте переменной false (значить не прерывать) и по мере выполнения метода проверяйте не изменилось ли состояние переменной на true если изменилось то прерываете метод. А в прерывающем метода присваиваете true и всё.

```
private bool _cancellation;

public void Start()
{
    _cancellation = false;

    // если _cancellation == true прерываемся 
    while(!_cancellation)
    {
        // тут выполняем работу
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}

public void Cancel()
{
   _cancellation = true;
}
```

Такой вариант даст возможность корректно и главное контролируемо завершить работу метода.

Я описал общий принцип, его можно модифицировать для потоков и прочего, это общий принцип корректного прерывания выполнения работы метода.

Comment: Попробую, на основе ваших ответов что либо придумать. Всем спасибо за отзывчивость!

Comment: while - для циклических операций. Таймер, фактически. А как быть с одной но долгой операцией? Понятно что так удобнее, но под кейс как прикрутить - я что-то без понятия.

Comment: @Monk: ставить проверки в тех местах, где можно прерваться, не оставляя систему в нездоровом состоянии.

Comment: while это простой пример работы, не важно что вы делаете в методе, бежите по циклу или ещё что-то самое главное время от времени проверяете условие _cancellation. Если true значить пора заканчивать с работой и выходить. При этом вы в методе сами контролируете когда именно это сделать (можете и не прерываться если осталось до завершения чуть чуть). Встретив _cancellation == true у вас появляется множество вариантов, прерваться сейчас, записать промежуточные результаты работы, что бы потом продолжить с того же места и прочее.

Comment: Фактически, вы предлагаете кнопку "Попытаться отменить", потому что метод сам решит, когда он готов к отмене. И, если он повис на какой то фигне, то он до точки проверки условия может и не дойти. Нестабильное решение, но может автору и подойдет.

Comment: Всё верно я предлагаю кнопку "Попытаться отменить". Если работающий метод повис то это проблемы логики этого метода и на совести программиста. Как раз в методе который делает работу и нужно проверять не повисла ли его логика, этот метод должен делать все проверки так как только в этом методе можно точно определить условия прерывания.

Comment: @МаксФадеев вместо bool _cancellation лучше использовать специальный CancellationToken. см. мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478290/196972).

Comment: @МаксФадеев Я описал только принцип, конечно CancellationToken это продвинутая реализация bool _cancellation, потока безопасная, работающая как машина состояний в одну сторону.

Answer (score 2):

Соглашусь с @Monk, сперва нужно создать поток, а потом при нажатии на кнопку уничтожить его.

```
Thread action;
...
action = new Thread(() => {
    _updater.Update();
});
action.Start();
...
private void breakBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
       try {
            action.Abort();
       } catch(ThreadAbortException exc) {}
}
```

Однако прерывать потоки не рекомендуются; `Sleep()`, `Join()` - пожалуйста, но не `Abort()`

Comment: Код, который я прислал, в нем создается пул потоков..  Может быть есть другой вариант? Например написать метод завершения или паузы в классе, который отвечает за обновление, и его вызывать?.. только опять же я не понимаю

Comment: @МаксФадеев Так и надо. Никаких абортов.

Comment: Грубое прерывание потока это плохо. Вы оставляете систему в неизвестном состоянии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin конечно я знаю, убивать потоки плохо, но предложил этот метод решения только для ознакомления, только в учебных целях, и только если у него там
`while(true) { System.out.println("Hello World!"); }` :D

Comment: Убивать потоки даже в учебных целях не стоит, существует достаточно мало случаев в которых убить поток хорошо, но в прикладной разработке практически не встречается.

Comment: @EvgeniyG не знаю, что у вас за прикладная, но закрытие окна\приложения должно закрывать за собой всё. И если что-то выполняется в отдельных потоках - то не ждать же их, когда их результаты уже не нужны? Зависит от кейса конечно, но Abort - вполне вариант.

Comment: если _updater.Update() сам запускает поток, то action.Abort() никак на него не повлияет.

Comment: @Stack естественно, однако трудно понять, что происходит внутри метода. ну, если он там не написал мега ассоциативное название метода:D хотя, Update() мало о чем говорит

Comment: @Monk при закрытии окна вы не только должны убить все потоки, но и очистить за собой занятые ресурсы, сохранить результаты вычислений. Но когда не важно что происходит с приложением и его потоками то можно Abort().

Comment: @EvgeniyG вот тут вы немного ошибаетесь. Сохранение результата вычислений - не должно зависеть от закрытия окна - оно должно происходить по решению пользователя или автоматически сразу после получения. Очисткой ресурсов я особо не заморачиваюсь, без результатов профилирования. В большинстве случаев GC справляется сам.

Comment: @Monk всё зависит от задачи. И GC не справляется с unmanaged ресурсами, а ведь их нужно обязательно освободить.

Comment: @Monk И сохранение результатов автоматически как раз и есть ситуация при которой нужно контролировать отмену операции и закрытия окна и убивание всех потоков в том числе. Иначе, если окно закрывается, поток прерывается в промежутке между получением данных и сохранением то данные будут утеряны.