# Как параллельно запустить 10 задач

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть список задач. В данный момент я их запускаю без поток последовательно. Но это все проходит очень медленно и я задумался использовать потоки. Только вот не совсем понятно какую конструкцию лучше и проще здесь использовать? `ThreadPool`. `Task`  и т.д.

```
var data1 = parse("www.ya.ru");
var data2 = parse("www.google.ru");
var data3 = parse("www.yahoo.ru");
....
```

Comment: _"какую конструкцию лучше и проще здесь использовать? ThreadPool. Task и т.д"_ -- Task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В дополнение к уже существующим ответам, возможно, в данной задаче вам стоит подумать насчёт Parallel LINQ:

```
var uris = new[] { "www.ya.ru", "www.google.ru", "www.yahoo.ru" };
var data = uris.AsParallel().Select(parse).ToList();
```

По поводу `Task`'ов, мне больше нравится такой синтаксис:

```
var uris = new[] { "www.ya.ru", "www.google.ru", "www.yahoo.ru" };
var tasks = uris.Select(uri => Task.Run(() => parse(uri));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Для того, чтобы не занимать свободные потоки без дела, я бы порекомендовал метод `parse` сделать асинхронным, тогда код становится эффективнее:

```
async Task<Data> parse(string uri)
{
    string content;
    using (var cl = new WebClient())
         content = await cl.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    // собственно разбор есть CPU-bound -- выгружаем в пул потоков
    return await Task.Run(() => ParseContent(content));
}

var uris = new[] { "www.ya.ru", "www.google.ru", "www.yahoo.ru" };
var tasks = uris.Select(parse);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Возможно, правильнее использовать более легковесный и современный `HttpClient`:

```
using (var cl = new HttpClient())
    content = await cl.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

Comment: _".ToList();"_ -- представьте, что есть 200 тыс. страниц и с каждой получается по 500 KB.

Comment: @Stack: В вопросе написано «10 задач». Если количество задач реально больше, то дальнейшую их обработку, без сомнения, стоит включить в pipeline.

Comment: у меня на выходе List<DB>. Почему то на select ругается

Comment: @Radzhab: Какой у вас код? На что и как ругается?

Comment: @VladD _"var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);"_ -- задачи, которые уже закончились, будут ждать завершение остальных.

Comment: @Stack: Угу. Если нужно обрабатывать каждую, то точно так же дальнейшая обработка должна быть по идее включена в задание вместе с загрузкой и разбором. Ожидать нужно лишь конечный результат.

Comment: @Radzhab если ругается на `Select` - значит, вы забыли про `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 3):

Проще использовать Task.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

static void Main(string[] args) {

  var urls = new [] { 
               // адреса 
             };

  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    foreach (var url in urls) 
       StartDownload(url);
  })
  .Wait();  // ждем завершение всех Task'ов, запущенных в StartDownload
} 

static void StartDownload(string url) { // для каждого url запускаем Task
  Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => Download(url), 
    TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent
  );
}

static void Download(string url) {    // выполняется в отдельном потоке
  // скачиваем и парсим. 
}
```

Если из разных потоков надо выводить статистику в лог, то пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/476958/196972).
Если надо прервать работу в Task, то пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478290/196972).

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду который вы приводите в листинге лучше использовать [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример:

```
var data = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => { parse("www.ya.ru"); } );
```

ThreadPool - же обычно используется если вам не нужно возвращать какие либо данные результатом.

Comment: а как подождать пока он закончит процесс?

Comment: _"а как подождать пока он закончит процесс?"_ -- см. .Wait() - в моем ответе.

Comment: Не надо Wait!!! Для этих целей давно уже конструкцию async/await придумали.